# Can't find button by using xpath by index in Odoo

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, odoo

I am using selenium python webdriver in odoo application , in odoo , when clicking on send by mail in his base module , selenium ide returns it's xpath as `xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[34]` & I used this in webdriver code as `browser.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[34]").click()`. It is not running and command line shows the following error -

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//button[@type='button'])[35]"}

what is the reason behind that ? also give me suggestions & correct code so that it will run

Comment: Please add html snippet for the concerned element in the application

Comment: <footer>
<button class="oe_button oe_form_button oe_highlight" type="button">
<span>Send</span>
</button>
or
<button class="oe_button oe_form_button oe_link" type="button">
<span>Cancel</span>
</button> , in this I want to access button named send & it returns that xml as I suggested before

Comment: can I use it by another type like find_element_by class name or id or by name , but how can I define it by proper name that it is "Send" button , because multiple buttons are there for a same class & they are distinguised by span classes ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments by OP, please try the below code to click on the **Send** button.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[.='Send']").click()
```

This will locate the `span` element with exact innerHTML/text as **Send** and click on it.

Comment: hey , thanks for your help , it is working , thanks a lot